# Set theory exercise in "The Foundations of Statistics" book

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I recently came across this question in a book I was reading (The Foundations of Statistics):

Prove that: $(A \cup B) \subset C$ if and only if $A \subset C$ and $B \subset C$.

My attempt is as follows:

1. First I prove the first direction: $(A \cup B) \subset C \implies A \subset C$ and $B \subset C$ by noticing that if $x \in A \implies x \in (A \cup B) \implies x \in C$ (because $(A \cup B) \subset C$). So it is implied that $A \subset C$. The same goes for $B$.
2. For the second direction, I need to prove: $A \subset C$ and $B \subset C \implies (A \cup B) \subset C$. I did this by noticing that $(A \cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) = A \cup B$ since $A \cap C$ = A (because $A \subset C$) and $B \cap C$ = B (because $B \subset C$).

Since I mostly do self-study, I don't know if this is right. Can anyone tell me whether this is correct and if it's not, what is the solution? Thank you!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Also looks good to me.

Comment: For the reverse implication, less elegant (but simpler) is:  $$x \in (A \cup B) \implies [x \in A] \vee [x \in B].$$  $$\text{Case 1:} ~x \in A \implies x \in C.$$  $$\text{Case 2 is similar}.$$